# Find : $\int_0^{\pi}\frac{(1-\cos px)(1+\cos x)}{\sin x}dx$

Tags: combinations, pi

How I can evaluate in closed form this trigonometry integral

$$I_p=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{(1-\cos (px))(1+\cos x)}{\sin x}dx$$ , $p≥0$ positive integer

Original question is
 find :  $(p+2)I_{p+2}-2I_{p+1}-pI_p$

What's about

$t=\tan (\frac{x}{2})$

Thanks!

Comment: where lives $p$ ? Is it a prime ? a natural ? a real ?

Comment: $p$ is Positive integer

Comment: By trial and error, it seems that for $p=2k$, the result is $4\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{2j+1}=4H_{2k-1}-2H_{k-1}$, where $H_k$ are harmonic numbers.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. Good eyes !

Comment: Actually this question is : let$$I_p=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{(1-\cos (px))(1+\cos x)}{\sin x}dx$$ , $p≥0$ positive integer
Then find $(p+2)I_{p+2}-2I_{p+1}-pI_p$

Comment: Please try to provide more effort and information to your posts. Spreading all over the place your homework problems with "what about this" and "what about that" will not get you very far.

Comment: Would you please tell from which book or source you got the question from?

Comment: Yes , but how I can send you the book

Answer (score 3):

For $p\in\Bbb Z$, let

$$I_p=\int_0^\pi \frac{(1-\cos px)(1+\cos x)}{\sin x}\mathrm dx$$

Note first that the integral is convergent, since $\dfrac{1-\cos px}{\sin x}=\dfrac{p^2x^2/2+O(x^4)}{x+O(x^3)}=O(x)$ as $x\to0$, and likewise $\dfrac{1+\cos (\pi-x)}{\sin (\pi-x)}=\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=O(x)$ as $x\to 0$.

Then

$$I_{p+2}=\int_0^\pi \frac{(1-\cos (p+2)x)(1+\cos x)}{\sin x}\mathrm dx\\
=\int_0^\pi \frac{(1-\cos px \cos 2x+\sin px\sin 2x)(1+\cos x)}{\sin x}\mathrm dx\\
=\int_0^\pi \frac{(1-\cos px (1-2\sin^2 x)+2\sin px\sin x\cos x)(1+\cos x)}{\sin x}\mathrm dx\\
=I_p+\int_0^\pi 2(\cos px \sin x+\sin px\cos x)(1+\cos x)\mathrm dx\\
=I_p+2\int_0^\pi \sin[(p+1)x](1+\cos x)\mathrm dx\\
=I_p+2\int_0^\pi \sin(p+1)x+\frac{\sin(p+2)x+\sin px}{2}\mathrm dx$$

Note that for integer $p\ne0$,

$$\int_0^\pi \sin px\mathrm dx=\left[\frac{-\cos px}{p}\right]_0^\pi=\frac{1-\cos\ p\pi}{p}=\frac{1-(-1)^p}{p}$$

To simplify the notation, we will still use this formula when $p=0$, with the convention that the term is zero if the denominator (and then also the numerator) is zero, which is harmless, since $\int_0^\pi \sin px\mathrm dx=0$ then.

Hence for all $p$

$$I_{p+2}=I_p+2\frac{1+(-1)^p}{p+1}+\frac{1-(-1)^p}{p+2}+\frac{1-(-1)^p}{p}$$

We have trivially $I_0=0$ and $I_1=\int_0^\pi\sin x\mathrm dx=2$.

---

See below for the proof of your recurrence relation. Here is the derivation of $I_{2p}$ and $I_{2p+1}$ for $p\ge0$. Both parts rely on what is proved above.

Then, from the recurrence, $I_{2p+2}=I_{2p}+\frac{4}{2p+1}$, hence

$$I_{2p}=4\left(\frac{1}{2p-1}+\frac{1}{2p-3}+\dots+\frac{1}{1}\right)=4\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{1}{2k+1}=4(H_{2p}-\frac12H_p)$$

And $I_{2p+1}=I_{2p-1}+\frac{2}{2p+1}+\frac{2}{2p-1}$, hence

$$I_{2p+1}=\frac{2}{2p+1}+4\left(\frac{1}{2p-1}+\frac{1}{2p-3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1}\right)=\frac{2}{2p+1}+4(H_{2p}-\frac12H_p)$$

---

Now let $u_p=(p+2)I_{p+2}-2I_{p+1}-pI_p$ and let's prove $u_{p}=u_{p-2}$, then $u_p=4$ for all $p$.

Let $A_p=2\dfrac{1+(-1)^p}{p+1}+\dfrac{1-(-1)^p}{p+2}+\dfrac{1-(-1)^p}{p}$ and apply the previous relation $I_{p+2}=I_p+A_p$:

$$u_p=(p+2)I_{p+2}-2I_{p+1}-pI_p=(p+2)I_p+(p+2)A_p-2I_{p-1}-2A_{p-1}
-pI_{p-2}-pA_{p-2}\\
=pI_p-2I_{p-1}-(p-2)I_{p-2}+(p+2)A_p-2A_{p-1}-pA_{p-2}+2I_p-2I_{p-2}$$

And $2I_p-2I_{p-2}=2A_{p-2}$, hence

$$u_{p}-u_{p-2}=(p+2)A_p-2A_{p-1}-(p-2)A_{p-2}$$

$$u_{p}-u_{p-2}=(p+2)\left[2\dfrac{1+(-1)^p}{p+1}+\dfrac{1-(-1)^p}{p+2}+\dfrac{1-(-1)^p}{p}\right]-2\left[2\dfrac{1-(-1)^p}{p}+\dfrac{1+(-1)^p}{p+1}+\dfrac{1+(-1)^p}{p-1}\right]-(p-2)\left[2\dfrac{1+(-1)^p}{p-1}+\dfrac{1-(-1)^p}{p}+\dfrac{1-(-1)^p}{p-2}\right]$$

$$u_{p}-u_{p-2}=\left[2\frac{p+2}{p+1}-\frac{2}{p+1}-\frac{2}{p-1}-2\frac{p-2}{p-1}\right](1+(-1)^p)+\left[\frac{p+2}{p+2}+\frac{p+2}{p}-\frac{4}{p}-\frac{p-2}{p}-\frac{p-2}{p-2}\right](1-(-1)^p)$$

And finally $u_{p}-u_{p-2}=0$.

We have yet to prove $u_0=u_1=4$. To achieve this, use again the recurrence relation $I_{p+2}=I_p+A_p$ to compute $I_2$ and $I_3$, as we already know $I_0=0$ and $I_1=2$. We get $I_2=4$ and $I_3=\frac{14}{3}$.

Then

$$u_0=2I_2-2I_1-0I_0=8-4=4$$
$$u_1=3I_3-2I_2-I_1=14-8-2=4$$

And we are done, $(p+2)I_{p+2}-2I_{p+1}-pI_p=4$ for all $p\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I really wonder what could be the result for $=2k+1$. I tried combinations of harmonic numbers after you nice result for $p=2k$ but no success. Cheers :-)

Comment: Wow! Thanks what's about : $(p+2)I_{p+2}-2I_{p+1}-pI_p$

Comment: @SophiaMaths I'm still writing on this. The remaining integral is easy to compute, you have then a 2-term recurrence.

Comment: OK I'm waiting you thank you very Much sir

Comment: Thanks you very much beautiful ideas